# boto3 generate_presigned_url with SSE encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, boto3

I am looking for examples to generate presigned url using boto3 and sse encryption.

Here is my code so far

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                                  region_name='ap-south-1',
                                  endpoint_url='http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
                                  config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
                                  )
        try:
            response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                        Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                                'Key': object_name},
                                                        ExpiresIn=expiration)
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error("In client error exception code")
            logging.error(e)
            return None
```

I am struggling to find the right parameters to use SSE encryption. 
I am able to use PUT call to upload a file. I would also like to know the headers to use from the client side to adhere to sse encryption.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do it? I have the exact same requirement and am unable to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

access_key = "..."
secret_key = "..."
bucket = "..."
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
              aws_access_key_id=access_key,
              aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
return(s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': bucket,
        'Key': filename,
        'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'AES256',
    }
))
```

Also add the header:-

```
'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256'
```

in the front end code while calling the presigned url

Answer (score -1):

You can add **Conditions** to the pre-signed URL that must be met for the upload to be valid. This could probably include `x-amz-server-side-encryption`.

See: [Creating a POST Policy - Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html)

Alternatively, you could add a bucket policy that denies any request that is *not* encrypted.

See: [How to Prevent Uploads of Unencrypted Objects to Amazon S3 | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3/)

Comment: Should this be sent as part of a header? x-amz-server-side-encryption
As I am using the PUT option, should this be sent as part of query string instead? I get the pre-signed UrL from the server code shown above.

Comment: I do see this as part of the query string ```x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm``` but I have sse-s3 enabled on the bucket.

Comment: My only experience is with the code snippet on [Correct S3 Policy For Pre-Signed URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693952/174777) that creates a pre-signed URL with conditions.