# Minimum Policy requirement for a Lambda function for generating presigned S3 urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam

What I am trying to do here is create a lambda function to generate a presigned url for an object in S3 bucket. So the code for the function works as long as it has Full Access to S3. But when I try to restrict that by just adding the GetObject policy, the link shows access denied.

Here is my Lambda function

```
import boto3
import logging
import os
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """ Receives the date of the file as an input, and
    creates a presigned url to download the file
    args:
        - date
    returns:
        - response
    """
    bucket = os.environ["BUCKET_NAME"]
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            'get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': bucket,
                'Key': event['object_name']
            },
            ExpiresIn=3600
            )
        return response
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        raise
```

And here is my template file, for SAM deployment

```
GetReportFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub 'getreport-${AWS::StackName}'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: !Ref LunchOrderBucket
      Runtime: python3.9
      PackageType: Zip
      CodeUri: src/get_report
      Handler: get_report.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt GetReportFunctionRole.Arn
      # Policies:
      #   - S3FullAccessPolicy:
      #       BucketName: !Ref LunchOrderBucket
  
  GetReportFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: GetReportFunctionPolicy
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource: !GetAtt LunchOrderBucket.Arn
```

I want to get this working with the least permissions required

Comment: Check this answer, much detailed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688422/correct-s3-policy-for-pre-signed-urls

Comment: I tried following what was in that post, but it doesnt seem to be working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is the permission for the objects under the bucket. You will need to have the policy to have the /* for all objects under it.

```
GetReportFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  FunctionName: !Sub 'getreport-${AWS::StackName}'
  Environment:
    Variables:
      BUCKET_NAME: !Ref LunchOrderBucket
  Runtime: python3.9
  PackageType: Zip
  CodeUri: src/get_report
  Handler: get_report.lambda_handler
  Role: !GetAtt GetReportFunctionRole.Arn
  # Policies:
  #   - S3FullAccessPolicy:
  #       BucketName: !Ref LunchOrderBucket
  GetReportFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: GetReportFunctionPolicy
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource:
                  Fn::Join:
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                    - Ref: LunchOrderBucket
                    - /*
```